# On codechef.com: TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

Tags: dataframe, python-3.6

I am facing this problem on https://www.codechef.com/ using Python 3.6. No such problem on my computer using Python 3.6.

My code used on codechef.com:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__ #This line does not work on codechef.com

#Read input
count = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

df = pd.DataFrame(count, columns=['count'])
df['old_index'] = range(len(count))
df = df.sort_values(by='count', ascending=True, ignore_index=True)
print(df.loc[:,'old_index'])
```

My custom input on codechef.com:

```
1 5 3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I realised my mistake. `print(pd.__version__)` on codechef.com shows `0.23.4` which is before version `1.0.0` in which `ignore_index` first appeared in `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`.